# WPF: Open new window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, window

I am trying to make a little Program were I want to open a new Window in WPF with a Button. It goes, but it like the mainWindow is closed and then another window is opening and I want ,that it goes "fluent",so you think that it is one window..
This is the code that I wrote for it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        this.Hide();
        w.Show();
    }
```

How would you do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *it does "pop up" and I want it so, that it doesn´t up*

Comment: @DropzZ1780 welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is  a little hard to understand; could you review the text of `it goes, but it does "pop up" and I want it so, that it doesn´t up if you know what I mean. ` .... maybe you mean `it goes, but it does "pop up" and I want it so that it doesn´t pop up; if you know what I mean. `

Comment: I have edited a little bit... hope you understand it now

Comment: It sounds like you want to replace the view in the existing window, rather than opening a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have too much experience on WPF. But being too much similar cases I've seen before, and Windows Form & WPF, in such issue, does not have too much differences. I'm here to try to answer, with tested on my computer and see if these opinions I give may helps you.

**TL;DR**: see last paragraph.

---

There will be 3 ways (or more?) to achieve:

### n windows , in which 1 is the main window

Just like the code that you have pasted to us. `Hide()` the main window, and `Show()` the sub-window.

However **this is really the last option I would suggest you to use**, as it would become when you have many windows to close/`Hide()` and to `Show()`. You will be resulting in not knowing how your stack of opening windows goes.

### 1 main window + n User Controls

This requires all the contents to be created and behaviours to be implemented inside User Controls. The main window will then be the container for the user controls to be docked into it `UserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`.

The main window may have a menu bar docked on top, which will always be visible over different 'screens' if not otherwise be configured.

Changing the docking UserControl of window from UserControl:

#### C# Windows Form

```
this.Parent.Controls.Add(new UserControl1()
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
});
this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
```

#### WPF

The main window should contains a *DockPanel* named for example `mainDock`:

```
if (this.Parent != null)
{
    var childs = ((DockPanel)this.Parent).Children;
    childs.Add(new UserControl1());
    childs.Remove(this);
}
```

### Completely replacing MainWindow

#### C# Windows Form

Since the C# Windows Form thing requires a message loop to hold a WinForm application to live, choosing another option instead of `Form` as message loop like `ApplicationContext` is required.

**Entry point**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(MainAppCxt.Instance);
}
```

**MainAppCxt [signleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) `ApplicationContext`**

```
internal class MainAppCxt : ApplicationContext
{
    #region Singleton --- we need only one instance for this
    private static readonly object Mutex = new object();
    private static volatile MainAppCxt _instance;

    public static MainAppCxt Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (Mutex)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new MainAppCxt();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public MainAppCxt()
    {
        ReplaceMainWindow(new Form1());
    }

    internal void ReplaceMainWindow(Form wnd)
    {
        var oldMainFrm = this.MainForm;
        this.MainForm = wnd;
        this.MainForm.Show();
        if (oldMainFrm != null && !oldMainFrm.IsDisposed)
            oldMainFrm.Close();
    }
}
```

To replace the main form inside forms, simply

```
MainAppCxt.Instance.ReplaceMainWindow(new Form1());
```

#### WPF

The App.xaml can still have the `StartupUri` be set to `MainWindow.xaml` for example. But creating new window will be like

```
var cApp = ((App)Application.Current);
cApp.MainWindow = new SubWindow();
cApp.MainWindow.Show();
this.Close();
```

in which to replace the "main window" role. So, if you close the window when for example SubWindow is the main one, the application will close!

Answer (score 0):

I would load all of my existing content into suitable containers (Borders or Grids perhaps). I'd then set the Visible property of the first container to False, and the Visibility of the second container to True. Exactly how you achieve that setting will depend on whether you're using a view/codebehind pattern or MVVM. From the looks of things you're using the former, so it would be something like this:

In your XAML:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid1" Visibility="Visible">
            <!-- Insert the first load of content here -->
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid2" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <!-- Insert the second load of content here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In your codebehind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Collapse the first Grid, show the second:
    ContentGrid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    ContentGrid2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```